# Getting file paths of subclasses

Tags: php, oop

To get the name of a subclass, I use `get_called_class()`.

What should I use to get the file path of a subclass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Reflection, specifically [`ReflectionClass::getFileName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php). How you instantiate your ReflectionClass depends entirely on the current scope, eg

```
// globally
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('SubClassName');

// within the sub class
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);

// within either sub or parent class in a static method
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());

// within either sub or parent class, provided the instance is a sub class
$reflectionClass = new RelfectionObject($this);

// filename
$fn = $reflectionClass->getFileName();

// what I assume you mean by "path"
$path = dirname($fn);
```

Comment: I need to get a path not a file name and it has to be the path to the subclass, not the current class :?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev I've updated my answer. Could you be more specific about what you mean by "path"?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Based on the name of the method, I wrongly assumed `getFileName()` returns a filename and not a path.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Perhaps you should have read the documentation I linked to. I'd also like to see a comment from the downvoter as to their reasoning

Comment: I did read it. That's a part of the problem. Here's what it says: `Gets the filename of the file in which the class has been defined.`

Comment: @Emanuil so rather than test it out, you just assumed it wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes. I tend to trust documentation.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev If it were to only return the last part of the filename, it would have said "base path" or "base name". Where the PHP doco mentions file names, it's usually referring to absolute paths.

Comment: You are right. Thanks again for the great answer! I wish more people would upvote.